# Visual Studio 2022 Test Explorer doesn't show any tests with a File/New "Test" project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-test-runner

Using the latest VS...

[image]

I created a brand new project with this template...

[image]

Everything compiles fine, but the default test that is created doesn't show up in Test Explorer.  I hit the green "play all" button and the output window shows 1 test found, but "No tests found to run.".

[image]

Is this a known issue?  Or what do I need to do to make Test Explorer show all my tests?

I can right-click/Run the test with no issues.  But nothing shows in Test Explorer...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filters were set to show failed tests only.  Once I fixed that, the test appeared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was something with access after I had deleted some folders.

Solution was to run Visual Studio as admin once.